# Negative text-indent

Tags: css, google-chrome, text-indent

So I have the following image replacement text:

```
<h1>Look at me, I am text.</h1>
```

That has the following CSS:

```
.parent-dev h1{
    text-indent:-999999em;
    background:url('images/thing.png');
}
```

Now before Google Chrome recently updated I have never seen the text not indent. However, as of a few days ago suddenly the text was showing up on top of the replacement image. Has anyone else seen this happening, specifically and only with Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/VanFB/

Comment: Weird. Works for me too. Must be a cascading style issue. Thanks for that jsfiddle!